# How can I modify the layout of the Leads Home Page?

Tags: leads

How can I modify the layout of the Leads Home Page? Can you please help me out

Comment: I want to add VF page link in "Tools" section.

Comment: Classic salesforce or Lightning Experience ? Please try to give us more details on your question, it's pretty hard to answer if we can't understand your context.

Comment: Classic SFDC it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortest answer: you can't do this with customization.

Shorter answer: It has been rumored that this might be something you can customize in Lightning (in a future release), but there's no way to do this in Classic.

Longest answer: You *can*, but it's not really worth the effort. All you have to do is build an entire Visualforce page that mimics the Leads Home tab, include the Lead "standard controller" on the page, and then override the Leads Home "button" that you'll find in Setup > Customize > Leads > Buttons, Links, and Actions. A few days worth of work to add a single link to the page.